# Play Framework not updating static files on refresh

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I'm using Play 2.2.2 and I found that for some reason, no files are being auto-reloaded at all. This applies to java files, scala.html view files as well as all static files (.js and .css) which are in the /public/ directory.

So far I've tried:

- `play clean; play clean-all; play compile` numerous times
- Completely removing the entire folder, checking it out from Git and running `play eclipse`
- Completely removing the folder, checking it out and running the play project without setting up eclipse first
- Running the application on Play 2.3 using activator (this works, but files are not being refreshed).
- Creating an entirely new Play project (`play new test`), running that and changing `index.scala.html` -> this also did not update in the browser
- Trying different browsers (Chrome, Firefox) for any of these scenarios.

I start the project by running `play debug run`, which yields this output:

```
~/path (master *) $ play debug ~run
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
[info] Loading project definition from /path/project
[info] Set current project to morphBMC (in build file:/path/)

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I understand the need to recompile Java files, but why aren't static files updating at all? How can I fix this?